# Can value of columns be lazy loaded in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lazy-loading

There is a table in the database that has columns `Id`, `Name`, `Group`, and `Text`. and sizes of values in the `Text` column are big (about 1MB to 3 MB).

If I use EntityFramework to update one row

```cs
public async Task UpdateName(int id, string name, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var record = await dbContext.TheTables.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id, cancellationToken) 
        ?? throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
    
    record.Name = newName;
    dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

This can be expensive to run since the size of the `Text` column is big.

The query like `dbContext.TheTables.Where(t => t.Group == "TheGroupName")` can be even more expensive!

**My question is "Is there a cheaper way to query data and/or update the data??? Can `Text` be lazy-loaded and how?"**

Comment: do you mind redesigning? moving `Text` to another table and ref as foreign key?

Comment: You can move the text field to an owned type, then turn off automatic loading (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041802/efcore-how-to-exclude-owned-objects-from-automatic-loading). Or define a 1-1 relationship, but map them to the same table, which is also equivalent.

Comment: Hi Lei, thank you for your answer. The 1:1 relationship is not ideal, because all other columns are metadata of the "Text" column, structurally they belong to the same table. :)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK EF doesn't support lazy loading value properties, where as I recall NHibernate does have this capability.

The typical recommended relational approach when you have expensive, but seldom needed fields is to split those fields off to use a one-to-one related table. I.e. TheTable.TheTableDetails which is where your expensive fields would live.

This way you can work efficiently with the base table entity and only hit the expensive stuff when needed. (Typically one record at a time)

Note that in your example you are missing an `await` on your `SaveChangesAsync()` call as well.

When reading information, leverage projection to exclude expensive fields/relationships rather that returning entities and either eager loading or risking a lazy load call fetching expensive values.

There is also a more "hacky" option that I wouldn't recommend except as possibly a last resort:

```
public async Task UpdateName(int id, string name, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var recordExists = dbContext.TheTables.Any(x => x.Id == id);
    if (!recordExists) throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
    
    var record = dbContext.TheTables.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    if (record != null)
        record.Name = newName;
    else
    {
        record = new Record { Id = id, Name = newName };
        dbContext.Attach(record);
        dbContext.Entry(record).Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = true;
    }
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

What this essentially does is check that the record exists without loading it. We then check the local cache in case the DbContext is already tracking it, if so we set the Name. If it isn't tracked we create a new minimal instance with the ID and the new name, marking the name as modified.

Such an approach should be used as a last resort and carefully as the "record" instance could be either a complete tracked entity instance, or a tracked incomplete instance. Later modifications that pass that entity onwards or return the entity would lead to potential runtime bugs. Realistically if that stub of an entity is attached and updated, it should be detached and disposed of after the `SaveChanges()` call.

Comment: Love your "hacky" answer!!! I was handwriting code in an MD style, tried to NOT make mistakes, but I still forgot the `await`. Guess that's why we need IDEs. lol

Comment: The other solution I found is to use EntityFrameworkPlus library https://entityframework-plus.net/ This looks very handy if I have to use EF without any raw sql.

Comment: Curious which feature in EF-plus helps there? Some of the features like IncludeOptimized look like they have already been incorporated into EF Core /w `AsSplitQuery`, though not aware of anything that allows you to easily break off columns. Ultimately the risk is possibly ending up with "entities" which aren't actually real representatives of the underlying domain. (and the bugs this can bring) EF Core has skirted this with things like supporting selective Include statements. Convenient but ultimately dangerous if abused/loosely used.

Comment: Hi Steve Py, I think EF Plus just becomes handy when doing batch data operations such as update, or delete. It doesn't only help with this question, but it is handy in general.

Comment: Yup, I was just curious if somehow they did manage something like a lazy-load property by extending the proxy or some behind the scenes magic which would admittedly be kind-of cool. :D