# EF Core calling stored procedure using FromSql throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using EF Core 7 and trying to call a stored procedure with the following code, but the EF Core query generator throws an exception.
I'm using the syntax from the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#passing-parameters) and I've [checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77321907/fromsql-or-sqlquery-was-called-with-non-composable-sql-and-with-a-query-comp) these other [examples](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx) and I just don't see why my code is failing

My code:

```
SqlParameter casinoState = new SqlParameter("CasinoState", casinoStateFilter);
SqlParameter isActive = new SqlParameter("IsActive", isActiveFilter);
SqlParameter prohibitedCountry = new SqlParameter("ProhibitedCountry", prohibitedCountryFilter);
SqlParameter softwareProviderId = new SqlParameter("SoftwareProviderId", softwareProviderFilter);
SqlParameter casinoName = new SqlParameter("CasinoName", casinoNameFilter);

FormattableString sql = $"exec CasinoIdSerach @CasinoState={casinoStateFilter}, @IsActive={isActive}, @ProhibitedCountry={prohibitedCountryFilter}, @SoftwareProviderId={softwareProviderFilter}, @CasinoName={casinoNameFilter}"; 
var casinos = _context.Casinos.FromSql<Domain.Casino>(sql).ToList();
```

I also tried `_context.Casinos.FromSql(sql).ToList();` with the same result

The exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: ''FromSql' or 'SqlQuery' was called
> with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider
> calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on
> the client side.'

This is the example code from MS and I don't see why this would work, but mine does not

```
var user = new SqlParameter("user", "johndoe");

var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql($"EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser @filterByUser={user}")
    .ToList();
```

I've tried a few variations of the SQL string e.g.

- `FormattableString sql = $"exec CasinoSearch @CasinoName='%test%'";`
- `FormattableString sql = $"select * from Casino";`

Now, the second one executes without an exception, but obviously the query is not what I want

I have successfully used the following with a stored procedure, but this example does not need to return a data set

`int result = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(query, parameters.ToArray());`

**UPDATE**
As requested, here is my `Casino` configuration in the `OnModelCreating` event

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new Configurations.CasinoConfiguration());
...
}

public class CasinoConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Casino>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Casino> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ToTable("Casino");
        modelBuilder.ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("TR_upd_Casino"));
    
        modelBuilder.Ignore(c => c.EWalletWithdrawalTurnaround);
        modelBuilder.Ignore(c => c.CreditAndDebitCardWithdrawalTurnaround);
        modelBuilder.Ignore(c => c.BankTransferWithdrawalTurnaround);
        modelBuilder.Ignore(c => c.CheckWithdrawalTurnaround);
    
        modelBuilder.HasMany(c => c.Bonuses)
            .WithOne(b => b.Casino)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    
        modelBuilder.HasMany(c => c.WebsiteCasinoReviewBonuses)
            .WithOne(w => w.Casino)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    
        modelBuilder.HasMany(c => c.Promotions);
        modelBuilder.HasMany(c => c.CasinoGameTypes);
    
        modelBuilder.HasMany(c => c.AvailableCurrencies)
                .WithOne(cc => cc.Casino)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_CasinoCurrency_Casino");
    
        modelBuilder.HasMany(c => c.CompatibleOperatingSystems)
            .WithOne(cc => cc.Casino)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_CasinoOperatingSystem_Casino");
    
        modelBuilder.HasMany(c => c.CasinoSoftwareProviders)
            .WithOne(b => b.Casino)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_CasinoSoftwareProvider_Casino");
                
        modelBuilder.OwnsMany(c => c.Alerts)
            .ToTable("CasinoAlert");
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(a => a.Languages)
            .WithOne(l => l.Casino)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_CasinoLanguage_Casino")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(c => c.TrackerLinks)
            .WithOne(t => t.Casino)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_CasinoTrackerLink_Casino")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    
        #region Intersect tables
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(a => a.BankingProviders)
            .WithMany(b => b.Casinos)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "Casino_BankingProvider",
                j => j
                    .HasOne<BankingProvider>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("BankingProviderId"),
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Casino>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CasinoId")
            );
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(a => a.BettingMarkets)
            .WithMany(b => b.Casinos)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "Sportsbook_BettingMarket",
                j => j
                    .HasOne<BettingMarket>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("BettingMarketId"),
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Casino>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CasinoId")
            );
    
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(a => a.BettingSports)
            .WithMany(b => b.Casinos)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "Sportsbook_BettingSport",
                j => j
                    .HasOne<BettingSport>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("BettingSportId"),
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Casino>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CasinoId")
            );
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(a => a.BettingTournamentLeagues)
            .WithMany(b => b.Casinos)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "Sportsbook_BettingTournamentLeague",
                j => j
                    .HasOne<BettingTournamentLeague>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("BettingTournamentLeagueId"),
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Casino>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CasinoId")
            );
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(a => a.Jurisdictions)
            .WithMany(b => b.Casinos)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "Casino_Jurisdiction",
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Jurisdiction>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("JurisdictionId"),
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Casino>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CasinoId")
            );
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(a => a.AllowedCountries)
            .WithMany(b => b.AllowedCasinos)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "Casino_Allowed_Country",
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Country>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CountryId"),
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Casino>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CasinoId")
            );
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(a => a.ProhibitedCountries)
            .WithMany(b => b.ProhibitedCasinos)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "Casino_Prohibited_Country",
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Country>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CountryId"),
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Casino>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CasinoId")
            );
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(a => a.SportsbookProhibitedCountries)
            .WithMany(b => b.ProhibitedSportsbooks)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "Sportsbook_Prohibited_Country",
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Country>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CountryId"),
                    j => j
                        .HasOne<Casino>()
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("CasinoId")
            );
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(a => a.CasinoAllowedUSStates)
            .WithMany(b => b.AllowedCasinos)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "Casino_Allowed_USState",
                j => j
                    .HasOne<USState>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("USStateId"),
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Casino>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CasinoId")
            );
    
        modelBuilder
            .HasMany(a => a.SportsbookAllowedUSStates)
            .WithMany(b => b.AllowedSportsbooks)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "Sportsbook_Allowed_USState",
                j => j
                    .HasOne<USState>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("USStateId"),
                j => j
                    .HasOne<Casino>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CasinoId")
            );
    
        #endregion
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Just type "sql" as a `string` rather than `FormattableString`. Also, is "Domain.Casino" your Entity class or a different DTO class? When using the DbSet you should be able to just use `_context.Casinos.FromSql(sql).ToList();`

Comment: `casinoStateFilter` isn't defined? Nor any of you other filters. The MS example is using the variable name is the he parameter, or the parameter name, not the parameter value.

Comment: Do you have any mandatory `Include`s in your model for `Blogs`? That would cause EF to try to construct a joined query like `SELECT b.* FROM (EXEC ...)` which is not allowed.

Comment: It IS `FormattableString` and I have tried a regular `string`. Both throw the same exception. There are no mandatory Includes. I plan to add some Includes, but I wanted to test the core query first. In my test case, some of those parameters ARE null, BUT I tested with only one hardcoded param as shown in the question

Comment: `Domain.Casino` is the entity, yes. The query returns a collection of `Domain.Casino` just as `_context.Set<Domain.Casino>().ToList()` would

Comment: What do you get from `context.Blogs.FromSql($"EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser @filterByUser={user}").ToQueryString()`

Comment: @Charlieface That was an example taken from the MS docs. `Blogs` does not exist in my model. However, I tried `ToQueryString()` on my `sql` query against my `Casinos` collection. I got the same `'FromSql' or 'SqlQuery' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. ` exception.

Comment: OK please show your full `OnModelCreating` config for the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, you have

```cs
modelBuilder.OwnsMany(c => c.Alerts)
            .ToTable("CasinoAlert");
```

which is an [Owned Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities). This is a child type that is always included. So it's as if every query you do, including `FromSql`, will always implicitly have:

```cs
.Include(c => c.Alerts)
```

You can't compose over `EXEC`, so the implicit `Include` isn't going to work.

- Either change your model to make it a regular property:

```cs
modelBuilder.HasMany(c => c.Alerts);
```

- Or remove the auto-include

```cs
modelBuilder.OwnsMany(c => c.Alerts, "FK_Alerts", n => n.Metadata.PrincipalToDependent?.SetIsEagerLoaded(false))
            .ToTable("CasinoAlert");
```

See also [EFCore - How to exclude owned objects from automatic loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041802/efcore-how-to-exclude-owned-objects-from-automatic-loading)

Comment: Thanks so much @Charlieface. I'll try that out and get back to you

Comment: You're a legend! That was it. The SqlParameter for `IsActive` is passing through `default` instead of `NULL` so I'm getting a SQL error. If I hardcode `NULL` into the query it works. The SqlParameter issue should be easy enough to resolve

Comment: Or you can pass `DbNull.Value`